# How to execute Custom action in Wix after Uninstall completed

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I have enabled logging using below code :

```
<Property Id="MsiLogging" Value="voicewarmupx!"/>
```

and I want to copy log file from temp folder to custom Log location.
I have written a custom action as below

```
<CustomAction Id="CopyLogFile" Execute="immediate"
          ExeCommand="cmd /c copy [MsiLogFileLocation] [LogsFolder]"
          Directory="TARGETDIR" 
          Impersonate="no" 
          Return="asyncNoWait" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  Custom Action="CopyLogFile" OnExit="success"></Custom>
```

After successful installation above code works fine but when I do Uninstall the code is not working.

Any one please help me to move file from Temp folder to specific folder after uninstall.?

Comment: What is the value of `LogsFolder` on uninstall?

Comment: What is the order of your custom action?

Comment: HI @KlausGütter
I have used  C:\Users\public\PublicDocuments\Logs as "LogsFolder"

BTW 
I got solution Below comment helped me to resolve this issue.
Please refer below comment.

Answer (score 0):

The specify the condition for the Custom Action to be invoked on an uninstall: `(REMOVE="ALL") AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE`.

This should work:

```
<CustomAction Id="CopyLogFile" Execute="immediate"
          ExeCommand="cmd /c copy [MsiLogFileLocation] [LogsFolder]"
          Directory="TARGETDIR" 
          Impersonate="no" 
          Return="asyncNoWait" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CopyLogFile" OnExit="success">(REMOVE="ALL") AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Custom>
...
```

See the full property references you can use in the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/property-reference).

Comment: I'm glad it did! Please mark the question as answered for other people's reference :)